# Bootstrap 3 outline on disabled context menu item?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am utilizing the following Angular context menu plugin:

https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu

Unfortunately when my items are disabled yet clicked, they show a border which I cannot seem to get rid of:

[image: Context menu border]

Should be a very simple fix but it seems as this is eluding me.

**EDIT:** Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NICOpwVclyg0sIODNECd?p=preview).  I believe the following *should* work but does not appear to:

```
li a:focused { 
 outline: none;
 border: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it! Pretty easy fix really.

When the menu items are disabled, the `<li>` element gets a class of `.disabled`.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 27px; top: 22px;">
    <li class="disabled">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Try this instead.

```
li.disabled a{ 
 outline: none;
 border: 0;
}
```

[Revised Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwewTtvGObtFOro4m8bc?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is more appropriate, but your original idea would have worked as well. The problem is that the element pseudo-class when clicked is `:focus`, not `:focused`.

```
li a:focus{ 
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
}
```